# wpf check list box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I m new to wpf.In order to get check list box functionality ,I have added below xaml to my code,but there is no output in my screen.only blank,what it could be?

```
<TabItem Header="Samples" >
            <ListBox Margin="10" Width="373" Height="236">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                               
                            <TextBlock Text="MyText"/>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="False"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>
```

Comment: Did you bind your list to any data sources? I need to bind your checkbox to particular property in your data source.

Comment: I have an example of how to easily create a Checked ListBox in WPF on my site that should help http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/

Answer (score 3):

just have a look at this basic sample

http://merill.net/2009/10/wpf-checked-listbox/

Answer (score 3):

List box is a bit wired for such task..Have a look at ItemsControl.
Here is the code i use:

```
<ItemsControl            
    ItemsSource="{Binding ***}" IsTabStop="False">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                Content="{Binding Name}"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
<TabItem Header="Roles" >             
    <ListBox Margin="10" Width="373" Height="236">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                     
            <DataTemplate>                         
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="MyText"/>
                   <CheckBox IsChecked="False"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBoxItem>Hi</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</TabItem>
```

and tell us if it still shows blank

Answer (score 0):

Better still, just use the new CheckListBox control in the Extended WPF Toolkit
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckListBox&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

*This might help*

1.Inorder to work datatemplate you must specify itemsource, here i have bounded a Stateslist a collection of items into it.

2.Also set the Datacontext to ViewModel or the CodeBehind as datacontext.

3.Datacontext will distribute the StateList properties collection to the listbox itemsource

using codebehind -

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    LoadData();

    }

using viewmodel 

public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Window1ViewModel();
    LoadData();

    }



//MyItemsource Property for listbox

private ObservableCollection<States> _stateslist;
    public ObservableCollection<States> StatesList
    {
        get { return _stateslist; }
        set
        {
            _stateslist = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => StatesList);
        }
    }

   // Sample Data Loading

public void LoadData()
    {
        StatesList = new ObservableCollection<States>();

        StatesList.Add(new States
        {
            StateName = "Kerala"
        });
        StatesList.Add(new States
        {
            StateName = "Karnataka"
        });
        StatesList.Add(new States
        {
            StateName = "Goa"
        });
    }
```

Window1.Xaml

```
  <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding StatesList}"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected"} Content="{Binding StateName}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxValue}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out it isworking..you are using TabItem but you didnt define it in TabControl

```
  <TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <ListBox Margin="10" Width="373" Height="236">
            <ListBox.Items>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                               
                        <TextBlock Text="MyText"/>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>

            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
 </TabItem>
  </TabControl>
```

If you are new in WPF use XamlPadX it will give you great help to practice out on it..